# javac: file not found: first.java Usage: javac <options> <source files>

Tags: java

I have a filename named "first.java" saved on my desktop in notepad++. When I run the cmd command "javac first.java" it gives me this error.

```
javac: file not found: first.java 
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

I know you are required to go to C:\Programfiles\java\jdk.

and in my C:\Program Files\Java\ I have thesE folders

"jdk1.8.0"
"jre6"
"jre8"

In C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
I have this folder
"jre6"

The Environmental settings are as follows

**CLASSPATH**
C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin
Variable name: LEJOS_NXT_JAVA_HOME
Variable value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin

**PATH**
Variable name: PATH
Variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin

Please tell me where I am going wrong.  I have read several posts on the Internet, and I can't figure it out.

Comment: javac is being found. The file first.txt isn't.

Comment: Problem from this question is NOT about inability to call `javac.exe` (so no need to fix `path`), but that WHILE executing `javac` it couldn't find `first.java` file which should be compiled.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and it was to do with my file name. If you set the file location using CD in CMD, and then type DIR it will list the files in that directory. Check that the file name appears and check that the spelling and filename ending is correct.

It should be .java but mine was .java.txt. The instructions on the [Java tutorials website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html) state that you should select "Save as Type Text Documents" but for me that always adds .txt onto the end of the file name. If I change it to "Save as Type All Documents" it correctly saved the file name.

[image: CMD DIR Example]

Answer (score 6):

As <kbd>[KhAn SaAb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249325/khan-saab)</kbd> has stated, you need to set your path.

But in order for your JDK to take advantage of tools such as Maven in the future, I would assign a `JAVA_HOME` path to point to your JDK folder and then just add the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` directory to your `PATH`.

```batch
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"
PATH = %PATH%\%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

---

In Windows:

1. <kbd>right-click</kbd> "My Computer" and choose "properties" from the context menu.
2. Choose "Advanced system settings" on the left.
3. In the "System Properties" popup, in the "Advanced" tab, choose "Environment Variables"
4. In the "Environment Variables" popup, under the "System variables" section, click "New"
5. Type "**JAVA_HOME**" in the "Variable name" field
6. Paste the ***path to your JDK folder*** into the "Variable value" field.
7. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
8. In the same section, choose "Path" and change the text where it says:

`blah;blah;blah;`***C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;***`blah,blah;blah`

to:

`blah;blah;blah;`***%JAVA_HOME%\bin;***`blah,blah;blah`

Comment: I am new to java and don't know where is JAVA_HOME ?? and in PATH I already have this C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin

Comment: I updated my answer to include instructions. This does not require the command line.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows, `javac` should be a command that you can run from anywhere.  If it *isn't* (which is strange in and of itself), you need to run `javac` from where it's located, but **navigate to the exact location** of your Java class file in order to compile it successfully.

By default, `javac` will compile a file name relative to the current path, and if it can't find the file, it won't compile it.

Please note:  You would only be able to use jdk1.8.0 to actually *compile*, since that would be the only library set that has `javac` contained in it.  Remember:  the Java Runtime Environment runs Java classes; the Java Development Kit compiles them.

Answer (score 4):

SET path of JRE as well

jre is nothing but responsible for execute the program

PATH Variable value:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin;.;`

Comment: or put same value for CLASSPATH variable..it ll solve you problem

Comment: Just to make sure i understood right you want me to do this
1. In PATH you want me to ad variable value "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin"
2. where do i put this "C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin"

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you have your path right. But what is your working directory?
on command prompt run:

```
javac -version
```

this should show your java version. if it doesnt, you have not set java in path correctly.

navigate to C:

```
cd \
```

Then:

```
javac -sourcepath users\AccName\Desktop -d users\AccName\Desktop first.java
```

-sourcepath is the complete path to your .java file, -d is the path/directory you want your .class files to be, then finally the file you want compiled (first.java).

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem. The origin of the problem was the creation of text file in Notepad and renaming it as a java file. This implied that the file was saved as WorCount.java.txt file.

To solve this I had **to save the file as java file** in an IDE or in Nodepad++.

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same problem because I wasn't in the right directory where my file was located. So when I ran `javac Example.java` (for me) it said it  couldn't find it. But I needed to go to where my `Example.java` file was located. So I used the command `cd` and right after that the location of the file. That worked for me. Tell me if it helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Java file execution procedure:
After you saved a file MyFirstJavaProgram2.java

Enter the whole Path of "Javac" followed by java file 
For executing output
Path of  followed by comment <-cp> followed by  followed by

## Given below is the example of execution

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin>javac C:\Sample\MyFirstJavaProgram2.java

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin>java -cp C:\Sample MyFirstJavaProgram2

Hello World

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this issue occurs, If you are creating a java file for the first time in your system. The Extension of your Java file gets saved as the text file.

e.g ***Example.java.txt (wrong extension)***

You need to change the text file extension to java file.

It should be like:

***Example.java (right extension)***

Answer (score 0):

If this is the problem then go to the place where the javac is present and then type

1. notepad Yourfilename.java
2. it will ask for creation of the file
3. say yes and copy the code from your previous source file to this file
4. now execute the cmd------>javac Yourfilename.java

It will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

First set your path to C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/bin in the environment variables.
Say, your file is saved in the C: drive
Now open the command prompt and move to the directory using c:
javac Filename.java
java Filename

Make sure you save the file name as .java.

If it is saved as a text file name then file not found error results as it cannot the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I executed the program without environment variable configured.

Java file execution procedure:
After you saved a file MyFirstJavaProgram.java

Enter the whole Path of "Javac" followed by java file 
For executing output
Path of  followed by comment <-cp> followed by  followed by

## Given below is the example of execution

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin>javac C:\Sample\MyFirstJavaProgram2.java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin>java -cp C:\Sample MyFirstJavaProgram2
Hello World

Comment: Could you please provide additional information indicating how / why this will resolve the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

just open file 
then click on save as
then name it as first.java
then in that box there is another dropdown in that dropdown (save as type) select type as all
and save it
now you can compile it

Answer (score 0):

first set the path of jdk bin 
steps to be follow:
 - open computer properties.
 - Advanced system settings
 - Environment Variables
look for the system variables
 -Click on the "path" variable 
 - Edit
copy the jdk bin path and done.

The Problem is you just open the command prompt which is default set on current user like "C:\users\ABC>"
You have to change the location where your .java file store like "D:\javafiles>"

Now you are able to run the command `javac filename.java`

Answer (score 0):

if your file located different folder

```
cd cd C:\Users\Owner\IdeaProjects\headFirst\sink-startups-game
```

then `cd src`

If you have just one file that located somewhere press `Shift+right click -> Copy file Path` and then you can execute same way : `cd + path(Ctrl+v)`

to see files in that directory -  `dir` +Enter

```
javac filename.java
```

then `java filename`

To compile all files in given directory: `javac *.java`
then easyly you can use `java anyfilename`

Answer (score 0):

There was an extra space in my case. I wrote **MyFile .java** instead of **MyFile.java**. I corrected this mistake and I was free of this issue.