# Problems with setting up PATH in Java

Tags: java, path, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10, JDK 10.0.1.

I'm trying to compile a program using the command line but whenever I try to specify javac it does not work. It will say one of two messages depending on the method.

**Method 1**
Using the JAVA_HOME method, I'll type `javac Example.java` in the command line and it will say:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**Path Setup for Method #1:**
https://gyazo.com/3503ef29c48175385768d8cd9b068ce4

**Method 2**
Using the direct Java bin path method:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
```

The output will be:

```
javac: file not found: Example.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

**Path Setup for Method #2:**
In the Environment Variables -> System variables I've tried to add the Java bin path to the "Path" variable. I tried adding "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin" at the front and end of the path like so:

1. Front: https://gyazo.com/22d4e4ac35a34af5d1333b74e7c16c88
2. End: https://gyazo.com/f066abbd45a5f16f4c49232890263299

**Sources:**

1. [javac is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)
2. [javac: file not found: first.java Usage: javac <options> <source files>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587840/javac-file-not-found-first-java-usage-javac-options-source-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a Java program from the command line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows)

Comment: Please do not add meta-commentary ('reopened') or pleading ('help please') to titles.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize it was against the rules to ask for help politely (using please). Not trying to sound like a smart-ass by the way, I am being sincere. As for re-opened I added that because anyone who had seen I put "Solved" earlier would assume it's closed, but it's not and I still needed help. Good to know though, will not do again. As for the duplicate, it does not appear to be. My issue is different than theirs from what I read.

Comment: It's not so much as a hard-and-fast rule as it is a guideline about clarity; people who add chatty material to their posts, as if Stack Overflow was a forum, have not transgressed in a terrible way. Rather, we hope that [writers will notice the edits to their questions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50953386/revisions) and start writing in a more succinct fashion naturally. I commented in this case because I had to make an edit twice (in retrospect I suspect you just did not notice the first one, so overwrote it).

Comment: The reference discussion [is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/472495) and [this editing discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/472495) is in a similar vein. I wondered if this was a duplicate because, at its root, the problem is a Windows `PATH` not being correctly set for the binary you want, and that has been covered hundreds of time on this site.

Comment: Ah okay, good to know. Do I have to type "path JAVA_HOME\bin;%path%" each time I want to compile something by the way? Because that would explain why it didn't seem to work each restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your environment settings you have JAVA_HOME:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin
```

And in path variable you do this:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

So your path looks like:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\bin
```

Which doesn't exist.

Second thing is that JAVA_HOME should point to jdk catalog not bin

**Solution**:

Change your JAVA_HOME to this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1
```

Comment: Oh okay.

Now my JAVA_HOME is:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1

and my PATH is: 
https://gyazo.com/d67706bf8bd40de8887d699c5b164671

But it still doesn't work

Comment: You changed it in path which is incorrect. Change variable JAVA_HOME without bin and in path variable leave %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: Ohh okay. Now it half works unless I'm misunderstanding it. When I first open the cmd can I just type "javac Example.java" and it will find it on the pc? Or am I supposed to enter the path of the file first such as using "cd Desktop\JAVA\Example" then "javac Example.java"? If I just do "javac Example.java" it doesn't work but if I specify the path first then it does.

Comment: You have to be inside directory where is your Example.java file

Comment: More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137713/how-do-i-run-a-java-program-from-the-command-line-on-windows)

Comment: @PiggiesGoSqueal accept my answer if it helped you, please.

Comment: Done, sorry about that. Didn't realize there was another option other than upvoting which I can't really do because I'm new.

Comment: Sokalski Well.. today I'm having the same issue. 
Pic: https://gyazo.com/affb80b47fdfcb70944adce3a381d72b

Only change between then and now is that I turned off and on my laptop. How can I set up PATH so it works even after system restarts?
PATH Info: https://gyazo.com/7a248a44c21d832795f846c5d3cf7905

Comment: That is correct @Rafal  Sokalski. I had to go through the steps again to get it to work again. I'd rather not have to do that every single day after a restart. Any idea what could be causing this issue? Thanks