# How to call docker/javac within a bash file

Tags: bash, docker, javac

This is my bash script ("compile_java.sh"):

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$(basename -- "$1")
extension="${filename##*.}"
filename="${filename%.*}"
echo "$1"
echo "$filename"
echo "$extension"
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp openjdk:15 javac $1
```

And that is my try to call the bash script (i'm using Ubuntu): `. compile_java.sh TestJava.java`

And that is the "error" message:

```
TestJava.java
TestJava
java
error: invalid flag: TestJava.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: you need to set java path

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587840/javac-file-not-found-first-java-usage-javac-options-source-files

Comment: @DigvijayS that isn't working for me: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-15-jdk

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp openjdk:15 javac $1`

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, there was special characters in the bash file. This works fine:

`docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp openjdk:15 javac $1`

Comment: but you should probably quote your $1 argument: `"$1"` cf. https://www.shellcheck.net/